# html POST data not being sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html form that is being POSTed to my receiving php page. I'm getting to the receiving page and the querystring values are coming over, but none of the posted input values. **Yes, I am using name attributes on all my input elements.** I have examined the request in Chrome Developer Tools, and the input values are not being sent. I cannot figure out why.

```
<form method="post" action="Authorize.Net/ProcessPayment.php?UserID=3">

    <div id="dialogCC" title="Pay by Credit Card" style="display:none">
        <p style="color:black"><b>Credit Card Info</b></p>
        <p><input name="txtCCNumber" type="text" placeholder="Credit Card Number" maxlength="16" /></p>
        <p>
        <div style="white-space: nowrap">
            <select name="ccExpireMonth" style="width:130px;font-size:15px">
                <option value=''>Month</option>
                <option value='01'>01-Janaury</option>
                <option value='02'>02-February</option>
                <option value='03'>03-March</option>
                <option value='04'>04-April</option>
                <option value='05'>05-May</option>
                <option value='06'>06-June</option>
                <option value='07'>07-July</option>
                <option value='08'>08-August</option>
                <option value='09'>09-September</option>
                <option value='10'>10-October</option>
                <option value='11'>11-November</option>
                <option value='12'>12-December</option>
            </select> 
            <select name="ccExpireYear" style="width:90px;font-size:15px">
                <option value=''>Year</option>
                <option value='2016'>2016</option>
                <option value='2017'>2017</option>
                <option value='2018'>2018</option>
                <option value='2019'>2019</option>
                <option value='2020'>2020</option>
                <option value='2021'>2021</option>
                <option value='2022'>2022</option>
                <option value='2023'>2023</option>
                <option value='2024'>2024</option>
                <option value='2025'>2025</option>
                <option value='2026'>2026</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
        </p>
        <p><input name="txtCVV" type="text" placeholder="CVV" style="width:50px;float:left" maxlength="4" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>$80.19</b></p>
        <br>
        <img src="images/creditcards.png" style="width:218px">
    </div>

</form>
```

The html above is inside a jQuery UI Dialog, and the post is triggered thusly:

```
function showCC(){
        $("#dialogCC").dialog({
          modal: true,
          width: 268,
          resizable: false,
          position: { my: "center", at: "top" },
          buttons: [
            {
              text: "Pay Now",
              click: function() {
                document.forms[0].submit();
                //$(this).dialog("close");
              }
            },
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
            }
          ]
        });
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this occurs is because jQuery UI appends the UI element **to the body element**, and not to the dialog's container element; the form. This then causes the form submit to act unexpectedly, as all the input fields are outside of the actual form element.

The way to fix this is to [define the appendTo element in the dialog settings object](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo). Such as the following, where I append the dialog to its parent; the form.

```js
appendTo: $( '#dialogCC' ).parent( )
```

Full code would then be this:

```js
function showCC( ) {
    $( '#dialogCC' ).dialog( {
        appendTo: $( '#dialogCC' ).parent( ),
        modal: true,
        width: 268,
        resizable: false,
        position: { my: "center", at: "top" },
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Pay Now",
                click: function( ) {
                    $( this ).closest( 'form' ).submit( );
                    // $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function( ) {
                    $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
}
```

Note also that I changed the `document.forms[ 0 ]` to `$( this ).closest( 'form' )`, as I fear using the "good" old way would end up in conflicts easily on web pages with multiple forms. It is safer this way.

Comment: It does not work. Check this fiddle.Also check the DOM element. form is empty https://jsfiddle.net/wx5kj2po/

Comment: @user2181397 It works just fine if you load the required external libraries (your Fiddle is missing everything). https://jsfiddle.net/wx5kj2po/3/ Instead of testing this on JSFiddle, you should test this in a local environment with some endpoint so you can properly dump the request contents on the server side. Right now you need to read through the network requests to see what happens, not very good for efficient debugging.